# Java file exists underscore

Tags: java, file, path, exists

I'm trying to solve this issue. When searching I'm not able to find the file due to the underscore in the file name

```
    File file = new File(filePath + "file_2.exe");

    if (file.exists()){
        System.out.println("File found");
    }else{
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
```

but I need to leave it in, any ideas please?

Thanks for you help in advance. :)

Comment: _"When searching I'm not able to find the file due to the underscore in the file name"_ Not correct. Underscore is a valid character for file name in almost every OS. And Java does not have any grudge with underscore in files' names.

Answer (score 0):

Try using
`new File(filePath, "file_2.exe")` — note two arguments and absence of the `+`.

Maybe you're just missing a backslash at the end of `filePath`.

Answer (score 0):

provide the value of filePath variable and output of this program. There may be problem with the filePath, becuase of backslash instead of forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

Note the error in the line in Bold,  '+' is replaced with ','
**File file = new File(filePath, "file_2.txt");**

package Stackoverflow;

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileUnderscore {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Pravin";
        File file = new File(filePath, "file_2.txt");

        if (file.exists()){
            System.out.println("File found");
        }else{
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }

}
```